# Bad syntax error on define-type using #lang plai

Tags: syntax-error, racket

I'm getting a bad syntax error on this piece of code

```
(define-type OE
  [group (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?)]
  [sequentially (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?)]
  [together (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?)]
  [join (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?)]
  [arrive (expr OE?)]
  [give (expr1 OE?) name (id-ref1 symbol?) in (expr2 OE?)]
  [(string-literal string?)]
  [(id-ref2 symbol?)])
```

and more specifically, this error:

```
xxx:22.0: define-type: bad syntax in: (define-type OE (group (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?)) (s... (arrive (expr OE?)) (give (expr1 OE?) name (id-ref1 symbol?) in (expr2 OE?)) ((string-literal ...
  #(739 316)
```

I'm new to the language so would anyone be kind enough to tell me what's wrong with my code and how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The following are the problematic lines that are causing the *syntax-error*:

```
i   --> [give (expr1 OE?) name (id-ref1 symbol?) in (expr2 OE?)]
ii  --> [(string-literal string?)]
iii --> [(id-ref2 symbol?)]
```

As noted in the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html?q=define-type#%28form._%28%28lib._plai%2Fmain..rkt%29._define-type%29%29), `define-type` has the structure

```
(define-type type-id variant ...)
```

where

```
variant = (variant-id (field-id contract-expr) ...)
```

So, every *variant* must have a *variant-id*, and each *field-id* must have an associated *contract*. Violation of this is the cause of the syntax-error.

In the case of `(i)`, both *name* and *in* lack contracts, so a possible fix is adding contracts to the fields, as such (using `string?` as an example contract):

```
[give (expr1 OE?) (name string?) (id-ref1 symbol?) (in string?) (expr2 OE?)]
```

Both `(ii)` and `(iii)` lack *variant-ids*, so adding them will fix the problem:

```
[some-variant-id (string-literal string?)]
[some-other-variant-id (id-ref2 symbol?)]
```

Here is a possible rewrite of the type, with suggested changes:

```
(define-type OE
  (group (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?))
  (sequentially (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?))
  (together (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?))
  (join (expr1 OE?) (expr2 OE?))
  (arrive (expr OE?))
  (give (expr1 OE?) (name string?) (id-ref1 symbol?) (in string?) (expr2 OE?))
  (some-variant-id (string-literal string?))
  (some-other-variant-id (id-ref2 symbol?)))
```